# Running Rails from another directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does anyone know if it's possible to run rails from another directory. I.E.

```
ruby ../another_directory/script/rails s
```

It would just make my life easier is all.

Comment: Haha. Thanks Casper. I had tried it and discovered the following errors:

1) needed top specify the config.ru file
2) The project I'm working on also uses rack which needed my current directory to have a child directory tmp/pids

I got it working with the following:
mkdir -p tmp/pids
ruby ../another_directory/script/rails s -c ../another_directory_config.ru

Comment: Well that wasn't too hard :) However note that you could always roll it all into one command by changing the working dir for the command you run like so `(cd the_rails_path; script/rails s)`. You can also specify the pid path with the `-P` switch if you need to.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to run two rails apps as one... If thats right then there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Sounds like you got it working! I also really like the answer from your comment. You should post it as an answer; then if someone comes along with a better answer, well then you again! Also I would consider a `rake` task that drops into the directory and runs `rails s`

Comment: Just add the `rails` executable to `$PATH`.